# Variables in UICollectionViewCells change to different cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a shop menu for my game in swift. I am using a UICollectionView to hold the views for the items. There is a black glass covering over them before they are bought, and it turns clear when they buy it. I am storing data for owning the certain items in the cells' classes. When I scroll down in the scrollView and then come back up after clicking a cell. A different cell than collected has the clear class and the one I previously selected is black again.

```
import UIKit

class Shop1CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var owned = Bool(false)
var price = Int()
var texture = String()

@IBOutlet weak var glass: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var ball: UIImageView!

func initiate(texture: String, price: Int){//called to set up the cell

    ball.image = UIImage(named: texture)

    if owned{//change the glass color if it is owned or not
        glass.image = UIImage(named: "glass")
    }else{
        glass.image = UIImage(named: "test")
    }
  }

func clickedOn(){
    owned = true//when selected, change the glass color
    glass.image = UIImage(named: "glass")

   }
}
```

Then I have the UICollectionView class

```
import UIKit

class ShopViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

struct ball{
    var price = Int()
    var texture = String()
    var owned = Bool()
}
var balls = Array<ball>()//This is assigned values, just taken off of the code because it is really long

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     balls = makeBalls(
}    

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {        
    return (balls.count - 1)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Shop1CollectionViewCell
    cell.initiate(texture: balls[indexPath.item].texture, price: 1)
    return cell      
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! Shop1CollectionViewCell
    cell.clickedOn()
    }
}
```

I am wondering why the variables stored in one class of a cell are being switched to another.

Please ask if you need me to add any additional information or code.

Comment: Cells are used. It's an important concept in `UITableView`/`UICollectionView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely implement `prepareForReuse`, and set the cell back to its default state - which in this case would be with the black glass, and unowned.

You can still change the glass in the same way as you're doing in `didSelectItemAt`, but I'd recommend  having the view controller track the state of each ball.

For example, when `didSelectItemAt` gets called - the view controller would update the ball stored in `self.balls[indexPath.row]` to have `owned = true`.

That way, the next time `cellForItemAt` gets called, you'll know what colour the glass should be by checking the value in `self.balls[indexPath.row].owned`.

Lastly, you're returning `balls.count - 1` in `numberOfItems`, is this intentional?

In the case where have 10 balls, you're only going to have 9 cells. If you want a cell for each of your objects you should always return the count as is.

Comment: This still does not work. This does not change anything. I want for each cell to be automatically clear glass if it is already owned. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Where are you setting the colour of the glass now? If you do `self.balls[indexPath.row].owned = true` inside `didSelectItemAt`, and then inside `cellForItemAt` do `cell.glass.image = UIImage(named: "glass")` when `self.balls[indexPath.row].owned = true` then you should see the correct behaviour.

Comment: Also, don't set the image based on the cells`owned` value. Either pass the value held by the view controller into the cell, or set the image based on the view controllers value. Tracking the state of `owned` inside the cell will not work due to the nature of how cells are re-used.

Comment: Ok. I am now storing the owned values in the CollectionViewController class and am returning the owned value in the itemAt function. This is working. The prepareForReuse does not change anythigng but I will still keep it there.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you may have to override the following function

```
override func prepareForReuse(){
  super.prepareForReuse()
 // reset to default value.
}
```

in  class Shop1CollectionViewCell to guarantee cells will behave correctly. Hope you got it.